# Change attribute of all UL and LI tags on a single click

Tags: javascript, arrays, attributes, setattribute

I need to change the attribute 'aria-expanded' from 'true' to 'false' of all the ULs and all the LIs on a single click.
I'm having a hard time to figure out how to do that.

Here's the sample html

```html
<h2>List 1 </h2>
<ul aria-expanded="true">
  <li aria-expanded="true">Orange
   
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
</ul>
<h2>List 2</h2>
<ul aria-expanded="true">
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li aria-expanded="true">Mango
   
    <ul>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
</ul>
<h2>List 3</h2>
<ul aria-expanded="true">
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li aria-expanded="true">Pineapple
   
    <ul>
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li>
      <li>I</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="changeAttr()">Change attribute</button>
```

Could you please help me do that?

Comment: you need to put some js code before...

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just do `class=aria-expanded` and use existing examples for toggling classes instead of using a custom attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeAttr () {
  document
    .querySelectorAll("ul[aria-expanded='true'], li[aria-expanded='true']")
    .forEach(node=>node.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false))
}
```

```html
<h2>List 1 </h2>
<ul aria-expanded="true">
  <li aria-expanded="true">Orange
   
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
</ul>
<h2>List 2</h2>
<ul aria-expanded="true">
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li aria-expanded="true">Mango
   
    <ul>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
</ul>
<h2>List 3</h2>
<ul aria-expanded="true">
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li aria-expanded="true">Pineapple
   
    <ul>
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li>
      <li>I</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="changeAttr()">Change attribute</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried this and it worked!

```js
function changeAttr() {
 var myUL = document.getElementsByClassName('mainMenu');
 var myLI = document.getElementsByClassName('childMenu');
 for (var obj of myUL) {
  obj.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
 }
}
```

```html
<h2>List 1 </h2>
<ul class="mainMenu" aria-expanded="true">
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="true">Orange
   
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="false">Mango</li>
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="false">Pineapple</li>
</ul>
<h2>List 2</h2>
<ul class="mainMenu" aria-expanded="true">
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="false">Orange</li>
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="true">Mango
   
    <ul>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="false">Pineapple</li>
</ul>
<h2>List 3</h2>
<ul class="mainMenu" aria-expanded="true">
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="false">Orange</li>
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="false">Mango</li>
  <li class="childMenu" aria-expanded="true">Pineapple
   
    <ul>
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li>
      <li>I</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="changeAttr()">Change attribute</button>
```

Comment: This unfortunately sets the value on objects that may not have it. The code also only handles the `<ul>`s but thats minor. I would also note that using for..of is not supported in any version of IE.